# Mathematica menu-bar disappeared!

Tags: notebooks, general-utilities

The menu bar at the top of *Mathematica* notebook disappeared (don't remember which key I pressed). How can this be fixed?

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/ShowToolbar.html. What Mma version? Try, Alt+W - S.

Comment: Ver. 11.3, Windows 10.

Comment: If it is just one notebook, I would evaluate `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowElements] = Inherited`.  That should restore it.  If it's all of new notebooks, then swap `EvaluationNotebook[]` with `$FrontEnd`.

Comment: For me pressing F12 worked (you might also have to hold the Fn key).

Comment: Usually that happens to me when the bar is closing their kitchen.

Comment: @userrandrand Please take the time to write up your comment of using the F12 button as an answer.  That absolutely solved my issue.

Comment: @kickert Thank you for your comment, i just saw that my comment got quite a few upvotes. I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 5):

From the upvotes on my comment, it seems that pressing F12 (the keyboard shortcut for full screen) will solve the issue if you cannot access the toolbar.

Reference: [Keyboard Shortcuts](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Top Menu Bar and select consecutively: "Window>Toolbar>Ruler" and "Window>Toolbar>Formatting". You will see the familiar Notebook Bar. Notice that the "Formatting" part is somewhat "not so neat" and needs to be fixed. The default has been in a somewhat bad state for some time.